# DAO, Hibernate and sessions in web projects

Tags: hibernate, session

I have read a lot of question about DAO and sessions but don't understand problem. Now I use something like this: [core DAO](http://techtracer.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/daojava.txt) (I added some additional checks in core DAO) and [DAO implementation](http://techtracer.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/admindaohibernateimpljava.txt) for web project based on wicket framework. In general this pattern can be described like:

1) using 1 session per 1 thread;

2) never close session;

3) always commit transaction after action.

I test it using DDoS utility and this implementation work (100 connections per second). But when I increase count of connections I will have lots of exception about closing session and not started transaction. How I understand I should use getCurrentSession() instead of openSession() but when I modified method getSession() in core DAO using getCurrentSession(), I didn't fix bugs :(. Then I tried to use c3p0 and bonecp. But those powerful tools didn't help me. Maybe you explain my mistakes :( except bug in the DNA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DAO, which you copied from anywhere, stores the hibernate session in a ThreadLocal object, i. e. one hibernate session is bound to one thread, as you mentioned.

But you're doing a web project. There you should bind one Hibernate session to one user (or browser), i. e. to one Http session. But you do not know in which thread the request from one http session is processed. Thus in your solution the same Http session may get different Hibernate sessions or perhaps different Http sessions may get the same Hibernate session. This depends to your Http server.

Solution: Put the Hibernate session into the Http session (and do *not* use the ThreadLocal object). You get the Http session object with `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` and with `HttpSession.getAttribute()`/`HttpSession.setAttribute()` you can set the Hibernate session and other Http session related data.

Comment: Good idea. But in this case I must close session after each transaction and use session pool or do you have another pattern? And what's about hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread must it be changed on something another?

Comment: That depends. You can let the Hibernate session open over the lifetime of the Http session. If the user has to log in, then you can use the single Hibernate session as long as he stays logged in. You close the session when he logs out. (For this solution you have to log out the user automatically after 10min or 1h to avoid too many sessions. Or you use Object.finalize() anywhere.

If the user don't need to log in, then perhaps you always close the session and use a new for each request to avoid too many open sessions. The disadvantage is, lazy loading and update won't work after close.

Comment: I don't care about hibernate.current_session_context_class because I do not use SessionFactory.getCurrentSession. I prefer to use openSession and control the session lifetime on my own.

Answer (score 0):

This question already have an answer, but to give more ideas how to handle it for those who come here in the future (as me).

Currently I'm implementing an stateless Restful API so I don't want to use session or have any kind of link between user and the server. My solution for the problem was to clean the EntityManager after each request, using a filter (the same one that is used to commit or rollback the transaction). It basically removes caching from application, but I only need caching inside the same transaction, so it is completely fine and desirable.